# Connect read 'send' of undefined

Tags: discord.js, message

I use discord.js@12.2.0

---

Code:
let reviewChannel = client.channels.cache.get(reviewChannelID);

reviewChannel.send(embed)

---

Error:
A:\GhostBot\src\cmds\utility\review.js:62
reviewChannel.send(embed)
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
at Statement. (A:\GhostBot\src\cmds\utility\review.js:62:27)
at Statement.replacement (A:\GhostBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:25:27)

---

Comment: This error means it couldn't find the channel. Perhaps you used the incorrect ID, or the bot isn't in the right server.

Comment: What's your code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `client` is a [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object, `client.channels.cache` returns a [`ChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager)'s [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of channels, where its keys are [`Snowflake`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake). If you call [`.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) on the `Collection` with an invalid key, then it returns `undefined` as per the documentation. In your case, your `reviewChannel` variable is indeed `undefined` instead of a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel), as your error states it can't `.send()` off `undefined`.

So even though you did not include the part of your code that defines `reviewChannelID`, it's likely that there's something wrong with that variable. The type listed in the documentation for `Snowflake` is [`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). It's possible you wrote something like this:

```
let reviewChannelID = 123456789012345678; //number type
```

Instead of:

```
let reviewChannelID = "123456789012345678"; //string type
```

So if I'm not wrong, it should be an easy fix of adding some quotes to define `reviewChannelID` as a string.